# Create master relationship path table from two columns of user data: (1) Parent (2) Child

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a master relationship table that lists out all paths from a given data set. The data set is structured as two columns: (1) parent (2) child. I am hoping my master table is structured as Parent, Child_1, Child_2, Child_n...theoretically infinite. A parent can have multiple children and a child can have multiple parents.

I've tried loops and recursion unsuccessfully (new to programming). I've found similar posts but nothing specific to this problem.

Sample data set

```
[Parent], [Child]:
9, 10
9, 11
9, 14
10, 16
11, 16
14, 16
14, 15
15, 12
15, 13
12, 16
13, 16
```

Expected result

```
[Parent], [Child_1], [Child_2], [Child_3], [Child_4]:
9, 10, 16
9, 11, 16
9, 14, 16
9, 14, 15, 12, 16
9, 14, 15, 13, 16
10, 16
11, 16
14, 16
14, 15, 12, 16
14, 15, 13, 16
15, 12, 16
15, 13, 16
12, 16
13, 16
```

Thanks for any help you're able to provide!

Comment: If the number of children is theoretically infinite, this is not possible with SQL as the there is a limit to number of columns a DBMS product can handle. Providing the IDs of all children as e.g. an array or a comma separated list is however quite easily possible.

Answer (score 1):

Most often, rather than having a table with an infinite number of columns (one for each child) the paradigm used is to create a `mapping` table. Such as (this is psuedo code because you didn't define the language using the proper tag).

```
Parent_Table
   parent_id       int identity,
   parent_property
   other_property_of_parent 
   .....

Child_Table_Type_1
    child_id       int identity
    child_property
    other_property_of_this_child_type

Child_Table_Type_2
    child_id       int identity
    child_property
    other_property_of_this_child_type

Parent_Child_Map
    parent_child_map_id int identity -- Optional
    parent_id           -- FK to the parent table
    child_id            -- not a foreign key
```

In this way, you can setup as may new children tables as you like without adjusting the definition of the parent table each time you add a new child table type.

Then insert a single row for each `parent` in your dataset, a single `child` in your dataset and then a `Parent_Child_Map` representing the path.

**If instead a node can be both a parent and a child, (this assumes you only have one kind of node) then you may only need a single table (node) and the mapping table**

```
Node
    node_id       int identity
    node_property
    other_property_of_this_node

Node_Relationship
    node_relationship_id int identity -- Optional
    parent_node_id           -- FK to the node table
    child_node_id            -- Also FK to the node table
```

Comment: Thank you, Michael. I'm trying to do this in MS SQL Server (apologies that I was unclear). I'm hoping to have a single procedure referencing the original data set

Answer (score 1):

```
select [Parent], [Child] into #t from (values
(9, 10 )
,(9, 11 )
,(9, 14 )
,(10, 16)
,(11, 16)
,(14, 16)
,(14, 15)
,(15, 12)
,(15, 13)
,(12, 16)
,(13, 16))a([Parent], [Child])
```

Based on child table you can add chile table in join

```
;WITH cteTbHierarchy AS 
( 
    select 1 as a, t1.parent, t1.child from #t t1
    UNION ALL
    select a+1, t2.parent, t2.child from #t t2
        inner join cteTbHierarchy H  on H.child = t2.parent      
)
SELECT max(a)
    FROM cteTbHierarchy
```

It gives 4 so i used 4 tables

```
 select distinct t1.parent, t1.child as child1, t2.child as child2, t3.child as child3, t4.child as child4 from #t t1
left join #t t2 on t1.child=t2.parent
left join #t t3 on t2.child=t3.parent
left join #t t4 on t3.child=t4.parent
order by t1.parent
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!